# how to fill in the deployment values from the list?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

values.yaml

```
S3Catalogs:
  Catalogs:
    - CatalogName: BotVoice
      Url: "http://sandbox5.*.com"
    - CatalogName: WrongVoice
      Url: "http://sandbox5.*.com"
```

the structure specified above needs to be filled in somehow in deployment.yaml
tried different variants, with brackets [0] does not accept.

```
        - name: S3Catalogs__Catalogs
          value: "{{ .Values.S3Catalogs.Catalogs  }}"
        - name: S3Catalogs__Catalogs__Url
          value: "{{ .Values.S3Catalogs.Catalogs.Url}}"
```

that's not how it works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you were on the right path using `0` (and presumably `1`) to access elements of the `S3Catalogs` array in your `values.yaml` file.

The following syntax works for me:

deployment.yaml:

```
  - name: S3Catalogs__Catalogs__CatalogName_0
    value: "{{ index .Values.S3Catalogs.Catalogs 0 "CatalogName" }}"
  - name: S3Catalogs__Catalogs__Url_0
    value: "{{ index .Values.S3Catalogs.Catalogs 0 "Url" }}"
  - name: S3Catalogs__Catalogs__CatalogName_1
    value: "{{ index .Values.S3Catalogs.Catalogs 1 "CatalogName" }}"
  - name: S3Catalogs__Catalogs__Url_1
    value: "{{ index .Values.S3Catalogs.Catalogs 1 "Url" }}"
```

values.yaml:

```
S3Catalogs:
  Catalogs:
    - CatalogName: BotVoice
      Url: "http://sandbox5.foo.com"
    - CatalogName: WrongVoice
      Url: "http://sandbox5.bar.com"
```

When I do a `helm template`, following is the result:

```
- name: S3Catalogs__Catalogs__CatalogName_0
  value: "BotVoice"
- name: S3Catalogs__Catalogs__Url_0
  value: "http://sandbox5.foo.com"
- name: S3Catalogs__Catalogs__CatalogName_1
  value: "WrongVoice"
- name: S3Catalogs__Catalogs__Url_1
  value: "http://sandbox5.bar.com"
```

Is this something that'll work out for you?

Answer (score 0):

Would the [range](https://helm.sh/docs/chart_template_guide/control_structures/#looping-with-the-range-action) clause help?

So maybe something like this would work:

```yaml
{{- range .Values.S3Catalogs.Catalogs }}
        - name: S3Catalogs__Catalogs
          value: "{{ .CatalogName  }}"
        - name: S3Catalogs__Catalogs__Url
          value: "{{ .Url }}"
{{- end
```